# How to run an app on Android Emulator in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2013

I want to develop Multi Device Hybrid Apps with Visual Studio 2013. 
My problem  (I despair of it since hours):

When I create a BlankCordovaApp project, I can run this app with the Ripple Emulator of Visual Studio. This works.

But when I try to run it with the Android Emulator, I get the following error:

```
BUILD FAILED
1>  C:\Users\Sabi\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:932: The following error occurred while executing this line:
1>  C:\Users\Sabi\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:950: null returned: -1073741819
1>  
1>  Total time: 5 seconds
1>  Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,ant,debug,-f,C:\Users\Sabi\Desktop\Development\Learning\Learning\bld\Debug\platforms\android\build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-Dgen.absolute.dir=ant-gen
1>  Command finished with error code 2: C:\Users\Sabi\Desktop\Development\Learning\Learning\bld\Debug\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat --debug,
1>  
1>  C:\Users\Sabi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\node_modules\q\q.js:126
1>                      throw e;
1>                            ^
1>EXEC : error : C:\Users\Sabi\Desktop\Development\Learning\Learning\bld\Debug\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat: Command failed with exit code 2
1>      at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\Sabi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:131:23)
1>      at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
1>      at maybeClose (child_process.js:753:16)
1>      at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:820:5)
1>C:\Users\Sabi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets(99,5): error MSB3073: Der Befehl ""C:\Users\Sabi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\vs-cli" build --platform "Android" --configuration "Debug" --projectDir . --projectName "Learning" --language "de-DE" --buildServerUrl "" --buildTarget "AndroidEmulator"" wurde mit dem Code 8 beendet. (exit with code 8)
```

I found many answers which are about checking the environment path variables or something.
I've also checked the environment variables in Tools - Options - Multi-Device Hybrid Apps - Environment Variable Overrides. But they are right!

When I try to build a cordova app without Visual Studio, it works and the app runs on my Android Emulator.

But this works only, when I create a new project with:

`$ cordova create hello com.example.hello "Hello World"
$ cd hello
$ cordova platform add android
$ cordova build`

If I want to build the Visual Studio project with "$ cordova build", I receive the same error like in Visual Studio.

Thanks, Sabi

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and battled for days before I worked it out. Basically the CTP install does not install all the files because Windows Defender blocks them (which files, I don't care.)

1. Goto control panel & uninstall CTP2, Java, Git, node, apple stuff, android (Basically everything the original ctp install did)
2. REBOOT PC
3. TURN OFF Windows Defender & any other anti-virus
4. Reinstall CTP2
5. REBOOT PC
6. Use Android AVD to create a new emulator
7. Open Visual Studio & create a new Blank Cordova App
8. Run in Android Emulator
9. Turn back on Windows Defender & any other anti-virus
10. For existing projects you may have to delete the bld folder before running the project

Hope this helps

JohnJollyStupid